# Access to childs of my main GameObject. Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some childs on my main gameobject, what am I down wrong on the below code? I bassically want to access to the sprite renderer of the childs of my game object,
If I put that code on the direct child that have the sprite render I can access to the sprite with GetComponent, please if anyone know what can I do let me know

```
  SpriteRenderer sprite;
  private bool changeColorState = false;
  public float time;
```

```
  void Start(){
    sprite = GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
  }

  void Update(){
    StartCoroutine(timeOfColorChange());
  }

  IEnumerator timeOfColorChange(){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    if (changeColorState) {
      chooseColor(.5f);
    } else {
      chooseColor(1f);
    }
  }

  private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D otherObject){
    if (otherObject.GetComponent<Player>()) {
      changeColorState = true;
    }
  }

  private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D otherObject){
    if (otherObject.GetComponent<Player>()) {
      changeColorState = false;
    }
  }

  public void chooseColor(float float1){
    this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, float1);
  }
```

I've tried GetComponentsOnChild but it's not working

Comment: `GetComponentsInChildren` returns an **array** .. if you only want a single instance it would rather be `GetComponentInChildren` (note the missing plural `s`) ... and well later on in `chooseColor` you are still using `GetComponent` again .. you rather want to use the `sprite` field there

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the "sprite" variable inside chooseColor, where you're using GetComponent instead of GetComponentInChildren. Swap it for sprite.color and it should work.